# For loop in prime factorization calculator displays composite numbers as well as the loop does not restart

Tags: java, math, prime-factoring

When the for loop detects a number that is less than the positive integer inputted by the user and perfectly divisible, it prints it and that is because the for loop just continues counting through each number. However, I need it to prime factorize the positive integer inputted by the user.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrimeFactor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
        int Number = console.nextInt();

        for (int counter =2; counter < Number; counter++) {
            if (Number % counter ==  0) {
                System.out.print(" "+counter);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do to print all factors is to divide `Number` by `counter` when you've determined that `counter` is a factor.  You also need to try `counter` again, in case there is more than one copy of a factor in a number, e.g. 12 is 2 * 2 * 3.  Don't forget to print whatever `Number` is at the end, in case it didn't drop all the way to 1.

```
for (int counter = 2; counter <= Math.sqrt(Number); counter++) {
    while (Number % counter == 0) {
        Number /= counter;
        System.out.print(" " + counter);
    }
}
// Print what's left.
if (Number > 1) {
   System.out.println(" " + Number);
}
```

As an aside, I've also changed the `for` loop condition to stop at the square root of `Number`, because for prime factor trials, if you've found a factor greater than the square root, then you should have found the corresponding factor that is less than the square root first.

Additionally, normal Java naming conventions would have you name the variable `number` in lowercase, to avoid confusion with classes such as `java.lang.Number`.

Comment: It's necessary to print the last factor which is not caught by the `for` loop.  In a corner case such as the square of a prime, `49 = 7 * 7`, we don't want to print the `1` that is left over.

Answer (score 0):

Your on the right track you just need to divide `Number` (`num` in the below code) by `counter` in the loop:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
        int num = console.nextInt();
        console.close();
        System.out.printf("Prime factors of %d: %s%n", num, getPrimeFactors(num));
    }

    public static List<Integer> getPrimeFactors(int num) {
        List<Integer> primeFactors = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int counter = 2; counter <= num; counter++) {
            while (num % counter == 0) {
                primeFactors.add(counter);
                num /= counter;
            }
        }
        if (num > 1) primeFactors.add(num);
        return primeFactors;
    }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter a positive integer: 12
Prime factors of 12: [2, 2, 3]
```